# Critical Region and level of a test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, sampling, inference

A concept I'm struggling with is the type 1 error and the level of a test, for me the type 1 error is P(Wn|H0)
where Wn
is the rejection zone. Is it not a way to measure Wn
given that H0
is true ? So why do we reject H0
when the level of a test is too low? ( In my opinion, if the level of the test is too low so is the measure of Wn
under P(.|H0)
so we have less chance to fall into the rejection zone).

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.